# NVIDIA SDK is missing a header file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda, gpu, nvidia

I am writing a simple program and trying to include this file in my code `#include <cutil_inline.h>` but I am getting an error..

> > fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cutil_inline.h': No such file or directory

I have tried this but still getting the error

```
 Error:
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cutil_inline.h': No such file or directory

Solution:
1- right-click on project name in solution explorer window
2- Click "Properties"
3- in left window Click Configuration Properties -> Linker
4- set the value of "Additional Library Directories" to 
"$(CUDA_PATH)/lib/$(PlatformName)";"$(NVSDKCOMPUTE_ROOT)/C/common/lib"

5- Right-click on your .cu file
6- Click Properties
7- Click on Cuda Runtime API
8- Set Additional Include Directories to :
$(CUDA_PATH)/include;./;$(NVSDKCOMPUTE_ROOT)/C/common/inc;$(NVSDKCOMPUTE_ROOT)/shared/inc
```

Can anybody help me out here. ?

Comment: Can you please edit your question title into something more meaningful? Also can you edit your question and include what CUDA version you are trying to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note you are missing a header, not a library. Making changes in `Additional Library Directories` will not help you.

1. Find the path `cutil_inline.h` is in. Make sure your SDK version includes it; if it doesn't, see if your code can do without it. Also note that according to the comment from @talonmies, the `cutil` package doesn't exist in CUDA 5.
2. Put the path into Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories.

For me it's under `$(NVSDKCUDA_ROOT)\common\inc`, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: I think the problem is that he is using CUDA 5 and the whole cutil package doesn't exist in that version of CUDA